# Communicate with an External Accessory over Wi-Fi in an iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, communication, external-accessory

I am building an app which will communicate with an external accessory capable of establishing a wi-fi bridge.
I am not able to defer the situation that how do I establish connection with this external accessory and then the device should be shown connected in my app.

After connection, there are certain actions I need to perform on the device. So a two way communication is also a requirement. How do I initiate a connection and then communicate over it.

Is any Apple framework available for it. As I am not able to find anything.
If possible, please provide a sample code on how to achieve this feat.

Thanks in advance.